# How can I root my device?

Tags: rooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I root my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device)

What is involved in rooting an Android phone? I am thinking of rooting my Motorola Droid.

Comment: Please change the question title to reflect the actual question.  Also, this is probably too broad of a question.

Comment: I'd imagine this is a top topic that people would be looking for on Android StackExchange. It's an important question. It'd be nice if there were full answers detailed for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more or less the procedure I followed for rooting my motorola droid on android 2.1

http://www.droid-life.com/2010/05/06/guide-to-rooting-android-2-1-on-a-motorola-droid/

It was straightforward and error-free.  That said, unless you have a compelling reason to root your phone (like upgrading to a pre-release rom), I don't see why you should bother (go volunteer your free time to community service instead).

Comment: In that case I suppose one shouldn't customize any of their possessions without a compelling reason. I feel that owning something is all the reason someone needs to customize to their liking. And with a straightforward and error-free process, why not?

Comment: there are also much simpler solutions, like the one click root apps.