# How do I root my Android device?

Tags: rooting

This is a common question asked by those who want to root their phones. How exactly do I root my Android device? Are there risks involved?

Comment: [Starting Jan 2012 we are going to allow one "How to root?" question per device.](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/791/440) Just search for [rooting] and your device or refer to the index below. If the question doesn't exist yet, create one and add it to this index.

Comment: Does rooting have anything to do with Android version? Do different versions have different rooting methods on the same device?

Comment: @hims056 possibly, yes. Because the manufacturer could fix security holes that developers were exploiting in order to root a deviec.

Comment: Related: [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217116)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: ROOTING YOUR DEVICE WILL PROBABLY VOID YOUR WARRANTY FROM BOTH THE CARRIER AND THE MANUFACTURER. IF YOU DO NOT WISH TO ACCEPT FAULT FOR ANY ADVERSE EFFECTS OF ROOTING, THEN DO NOT READ ANY FURTHER. *HERE BE DRAGONS*.**

---

## Questions?

Before rooting, you might have some questions about it.  Fortunately, they've already been answered!  Refer to the handy list below:

- [What does "to root a phone" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236/1465)
- [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2885/1465)
- [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/164/1465)
- [What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1/1465)
- [Do all applications run as root on a rooted phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16367/1465)
- See the sidebar to the right for more potentially relevant questions!

## How do I do root?

Note there is no known method that will root all devices, nor is there any guarantee that any mentioned program or method will actually work. This is because there are many variables at play and device OEMs have no incentive to make the process easy.

A final caution: Your warranties *may* be voided, you may screw up your device, and there may also be other adverse effects. **If you do not want to risk it, stop now.** If you are not confident in what you are doing, please do not deviate from the guides and read carefully.

The easiest way to root your device is via "one click" methods, most of which are developed for more popular devices. Examples include applications (`.apk` files) you can run on your device, or software you have to run on a PC while connecting the device with USB. Other methods may involve many steps or manual editing of files.

Methods typically vary between models and even between firmware versions of the same model. **Check your rooting method is compatible with:**

- Your device model/brand (e.g. Samsung Note)
- Your Android version (e.g. 4.4 KitKat vs 5.1 Lollipop)
- Your firmware version (e.g. European vs. USA vs. Verizon telecom provider)
- Your hardware version (e.g. 32GB model with antenna vs. 16GB without one)

## Rooting Guides Index

These are links to questions on this site that have been asked for specific devices.  If the question for your device hasn't been answered, don't post a duplicate — you can attract attention to the question by offering a bounty on it, sharing the link, posting in our chatroom, etc.

### Acer

- [Iconia A100](/q/126840/1465)
- [Iconia A500](/q/16636/1465)
- [Liquid Mini](/q/11436/1465)
- [Liquid Z630S](/q/152771/16575)
- [Liquid Zest](/q/146390/16575)

### Amazon

- [Fire TV](/q/93520/1465)
- [Kindle Fire](/q/17482/1465) Version [6.x](/q/17584/1465) / [10.x](/q/38337/16575)
- [Kindle Fire 5th gen](/q/151046/71371) (aka 2015)
- [Kindle Fire HD](/q/49248/1465)

### Archos

- [Archos 70 Xenon Color (Android 5.1)](/q/157321/16575)
- [Archos 97b Platium HD](/q/83118/1465)
- [101 XS Tablet](/q/103419/1465)

### Asus

- [Eee Pad Transformer](/q/15544/1465)
- [Fonepad 8](/q/115092/1465)
- Fonepad K004 ([post deleted](/q/128258/1465) (aka ME371MG))
- [Memo Pad HD 7](/q/62597/1465)
- [Nexus 7](/q/37760/1465)
- [ZenFone 3 Max](/q/188655/16575)
- [ZenFone 5](/q/87939/1465)
- [ZenPad S 8.0](/q/129000/1465)
- [Zenfone 2 ZE551ML](/q/162470/196874)

### HTC

- Amaze
- [Desire 300](/q/89195/1465) (aka "Zara Mini")
- [Desire 500](/q/141404/16575)
- [Desire 625](/q/146249/16575)
- [Desire](/q/17587/1465)
- [Desire Bravo](/q/96301/1465)
- [Desire Z](/q/9012/1465)
- [Dream](/q/7660/1465) (aka G1)
- [Evo](/q/4250/1465)
- [Evo 4G](/q/30174/1465)
- [Gratia](/q/33524/1465)
- [Hero](/q/456/1465)
- [Incredible 2 (Verizon)](/q/34355/1465)
- [Incredible S](/q/18330/1465)
- [Legend](/q/38418/1465)
- [Magic](/q/2827/1465)
- [myTouch 4G Slide](/q/24882/1465)
- [myTouch Q](/q/74906/1465)
- [Nexus ONE](/q/6592/1465)
- [One S](/q/92760/1465)
- [One V](/q/39147/1465)
- [One X](/q/32598/1465)
- [One XL](/q/32752/1465)
- [Salsa](/q/44428/1465)
- [Thunderbolt](/q/18833/1465)
- [Wildfire](/q/8703/1465)

### Huawei

- [Ascend Y330](/q/88745/1465)
- [Ascend Y530](/q/106389/1465)
- [G330D U8825D](/q/47937/1465)
- [Mate 8](/q/134514/1465) (aka Ascend Mate8)
- [Mediapad S7-301U](/q/54173/1465)
- Nexus 6P
- [P1 U9202L](/q/71400/1465)
- [PLDT Telpad QS S7-961WD](/q/90268/1465)
- [STREAM X GL07S](/q/111544/1465)
- [U8160](/q/87461/1465) (Vodafone 858)
- [X3 U8510](/q/18158/1465)
- [Y210](/q/39222/1465)

### Karbonn

- [A7 + Smart Tab 7](/q/41654/1465) (possibly same for A5)
- [Titanium Mach Two S360](/q/120012/1465)
- [Titanium S5](/q/69849/1465)

### Lenovo

- [A660](/q/37693/1465)
- [A1000 Smartphone](/q/134979/1465)
- [A7000](/q/106518/1465)
- [S920](/q/91497/1465)
- [Thinkpad](/q/37322/1465)

### LG

- [Escape](/q/36412/1465)
- [G2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=45692679#post45692679)
- [G3](/q/93437/1465)
- [G4](/q/156323/16575)
- [Motion 4G](/q/47716/1465)
- [MS 330](/q/149845/16575) (aka K7)
- [MS 690](/q/77900/1465)
- [Nexus 4](/q/43906/1465)
- [Nexus 5](/q/57490/1465)
- [Optimus 2X](/q/40607/1465)
- [Optimus 4X](/q/40620/1465)
- [Optimus L7 II - P713](/q/48249/1465)
- [Optimus L7 II - P715](/q/120193/1465)
- [Optimus L70™ LGMS323](/q/117184/1465)
- [Optimus Logic](/q/40516/1465)
- [Optimus M](/q/19036/1465)
- [Optimus Slider VM701](/q/44054/1465)
- [P500](/q/37538/1465)

### Micromax

- [A089 Bolt](/q/106119/1465)
- [A25](/q/45002/1465)
- [A65 Bolt](/q/57637/1465)
- [A87](/q/38578/1465)
- [Canvas A1 AQ4501](/q/97044/1465)
- [Canvas A116](/q/106265/1465) (Canvas HD)
- [Canvas 2 A110](/q/42910/1465)
- [Canvas 2 Plus A110Q](/q/96209/96209)

### Motorola

- [Defy](/q/3632/1465)
- [Defy XT](/q/24446/1465)
- [Droid 3](/q/13147/1465)
- [Droid Maxx](/q/91541/1465)
- [Droid Razr](/q/46782/1465)
- [Droid Razr M](/q/78769/1465)
- [Droid Razr Maxx HD](/q/93449/1465)
- [Droid X](/q/22795/1465)
- [Droid X2](/q/46831/1465)
- [Fire XT316](/q/17887/1465)
- [Flipside](/q/36047/1465)
- [Moto G](/q/90002/44325)
- [Moto G XT1032/XT1033](/q/107166/1465)
- [Moto G 2014 2nd Gen (XT1063, XT1064, XT1068 and XT106)](/q/140648/1465)
- Moto X [stock Kitkat](/q/64990/16575)
- [Moto X Play](/q/185104/205764)

### Nook

- [Nook Color](/q/23313/1465)
- [Nook HD](/q/37112/1465)

### OnePlus

- [OnePlus One](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106856/1465)
- [OnePlus 3](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/177246/205764)
- [OnePlus 3T](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/177246/205764)
- [OnePlus 5](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/177246/205764)

### Prestigio

- [MultiPad PMP3670B](/q/47849/1465)
- [PAP 7500](/q/86148/1465)

### Samsung

- [Admire R720](/q/88997/1465) (Also known as Samsung Vitality)
- [Captivate](/q/20479/1465)
- [Epic Galaxy 4G (SPH-D700)](/q/27028/1465)
- [Fascinate](/q/48308/1465)
- [Galaxy A3 2016 (SM-A310F)](/q/170552/205801)
- [Galaxy A5](/q/117012/1465)
- [Galaxy Ace Plus](/q/32792/1465)
- [Galaxy Ace S5830i](/q/56355/1465)
- [Galaxy Alpha SM-G850A](/q/136858/1465)
- [Galaxy Attain 4G](/q/49925/1465)
- [Galaxy Chat B5330](/q/62108/1465)
- [Galaxy Core i8262](/q/128623/1465)
- [Galaxy Fit](/q/9338/1465)
- [Galaxy Grand Duos](/q/86319/1465)
- [Galaxy Grand Quattro](/q/92842/1465)
- [Galaxy Note 2](/q/39382/1465)
- [Galaxy Note 3](/q/91491/1465)
- [Galaxy Note N7000](/q/62613/1465)
- [Galaxy Player](/q/31895/1465)
- [Galaxy Precedent](/q/54013/1465)
- [Galaxy S](/q/20292/1465)
- [Galaxy S Advance/S II Lite i9070](/q/23884/1465)
- [Galaxy S2 GT-i9100](/q/88717/1465), [GT-I9100**P**](/q/28662/16575), [GT-I9100**G**](/q/22768/16575)
- [Galaxy S2 plus](/q/82582/1465)
- [Galaxy S3 i9300](/a/26880/16575), [i9305](/q/89370/1465)
- [Galaxy S3 Duos3](/q/110169/1465)
- [Galaxy S3 Lite](/q/91808/1465) (S6790)
- [Galaxy S3 Mini GT-i8190](/q/47805/1465)
- [Galaxy S4 GT-I9500 (Android 4.4.2)](/q/74616/1465) [(build XXUBMH1)](/q/56996/205764)
- [Galaxy S4 GT-I9505](/q/110955/1465)
- [Galaxy S4 Mini GT-I9195](/a/54075/9240)
- [Galaxy S4 SCH-I545](/q/49766/1465)
- [Galaxy S4 SGH-I337](/q/55818/1465)
- [Galaxy S4 SGH-M919](/q/93443/1465)
- Galaxy S5 [SM-G900V (Verizon) on Lollipop](/q/146082/16575)
- [Galaxy S6 / S6 Edge](/q/134766/1465) / [S6 @ Sprint](/q/135358/16575) / [S6 Edge @ Verizon](/q/200142/16575) (S6 Edge is S6 but has curved screen)
- [Galaxy S7 / S7 Edge (us carriers)](/q/147825/16575)
- [Galaxy SL GT i9003](/q/32461/1465)
- [Galaxy Star Duos S5282](/q/56411/1465)
- [Galaxy Star Pro (S7260)](/q/58874/1465)
- [Galaxy Stellar](/q/53601/1465)
- [Galaxy Tab](/q/8777/1465)
- [Galaxy Tab A (SM-P550)](/q/155195/205764)
- [Galaxy Tab 10.1](/q/18243/1465)
- [Galaxy Tab 3 10.1](/q/52106/1465)
- [Galaxy V](/q/115665/1465)
- [Galaxy Young 2 (SM-G130HN)](/q/167180/205764)
- [Infuse (i997)](/q/6776/1465)
- [Infuse 4G](/q/16366/1465)
- [J5](/q/188752/16575)
- [Nexus S](/q/18085/1465) | [on Gingerbread](/q/20706/16575)
- [Spica](/q/30/1465)
- [Xcover3 (SM-G388F)](/q/140017/1465)

### Sony

- [Xperia Arc S](/q/44249/1465)
- [Xperia J](/q/81215/1465)
- [Xperia Mini ST15i](/q/25065/1465)
- [Xperia Mini Pro SK17i](/q/98051/1465)
- [Xperia Neo V (MT11i)](/q/28826/1465)
- [Xperia P](/q/65838/1465)
- [Xperia Play](/q/29641/1465)
- [Xperia Pro MK16a/i](/q/22991/1465)
- [Xperia Ray ST18i](/q/41548/1465)
- [Xperia S](/q/28441/1465)
- [Xperia Sola (MT27i)](/q/58906/1465)
- [Xperia SP (C530x)](/q/63123/1465)
- [Xperia Tipo](/q/38614/1465)
- [Xperia Tipo Dual](/q/35302/1465)
- [Xperia T2 Ultra Dual](/q/82852/1465)
- [Xperia T3](/q/106963/1465)
- [Xperia U](/q/78943/1465)
- [Xperia X8](/q/4789/1465)
- [Xperia Z1](/q/68807/1465)
- [Xperia Z2](/q/154287/16575)
- [Xperia Z3](/q/106025/1465)

### SpreadTrum

- [SC6830](/q/37982/1465)
- [SP8810](/q/35651/1465) (Wynncom G1)

### Xolo

- [Xolo One](/q/102197/1465)
- [Xolo Q1010i](/q/93375/1465)

### ZTE

- [DL 800](/q/146251/16575)
- [Fury](/q/39513/1465)
- [Score](/q/15613/1465)
- [Optik](/q/124974/1465)
- [Origin](/q/37365/1465)
- [Prestige](/q/129839/1465)
- [Zinger (Z667T)](/q/116477/1465)

### Other

- [Alcatel OT-997D](/q/48810/1465)
- [Alcatel One Touch Mini Idol 2](/q/96482/1465)
- [Android Emulator](/q/4067/1465)
- [Arnova GBook](/q/32712/1465)
- [Azpen A727](/q/116494/1465)
- [Casio Commando](/q/32371/1465)
- [Celkon A95 Pro](/q/44418/1465)
- [Chinavasion TechPad](/q/2164/1465)
- [Cruz Tablet](/q/4534/1465)
- [Dell Streak 5 / Mini 5](/q/18171/1465)
- [Doogee Voyager2 DG310](/q/126334/1465)
- [Emdoor EM79 c](/q/48950/1465)
- [EPad MX1014](/q/45060/1465)
- [Freelander PX2 tablet](/q/85586/1465)
- [General Mobile e-tab 7b](/q/49535/1465)
- [Gionee P5W](/q/190773/16575)
- [HP Pro Slate 12](/q/127473/1465)
- [Innos A35](/q/44699/1465)
- [Kyocera Echo](/q/23610/1465)
- [Lava Iris 504q](/q/89495/1465)
- [Mpie MP707](/q/88961/1465)
- [Oppo N1](/q/106699/1465)
- [Pandigital Novel](/q/13263/1465)
- [Pantech Crossover P8000](/q/61192/1465)
- [Prizma VSGK845](/q/90009/1465)
- [RealPower MT65515-C910](/q/44680/1465)
- [TCL Idol X (S950)](/q/52309/1465)
- [Teac TC-7120](/q/28882/1465)
- [Teclast tPad](/q/23504/1465)
- [Toshiba AT100](/q/48059/1465)
- [Viewsonic gTablet](/q/11369/1465)
- [Xiaomi Mi A1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/187630/16575)
- [Wileyfox Swift](/q/141405/16575)
- [Yarvik tab 411](/q/43461/1465)

## Methods/Apps

- Chainfire's [CF-Autoroot](http://autoroot.chainfire.eu/) (follow link for a list of supported devices). Supports plenty of Samsung devices, plus some Motorolas and the Nexus line
- [Droid X Recovery Bootstrap](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2010/08/droid-x-recovery.html) (Motorola Droid/Droid2/Droid X, probably Android 2.x only)
- [Framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2130276) - One-click rooting and unrooting; supports a number of devices using Qualcomm, MTK, Exynos, Omap and other SOCs (Android 2.x to 4.x)
- [Gingerbread exploit app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1044765) - Works on 2.1 and 2.2, as well as early 2.3 releases (hence the name).
- [Gnex Toolkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1614827&nocache=1) - Software for rooting and handling your Galaxy Nexus phone.
- [Google Nexus 7 Toolkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1809195) - Software for rooting and handling your Nexus 7 tablet.
- [iRoot](http://www.iroot.com/) a One Click Root (see [here for supported devices](http://www.iroot.com/supported-devices)
- [Kingoapp Root](http://www.kingoapp.com/): Pratically roots most androids in 1-click and supports Android 4.1 to 6.0. Even unlocks some bootloaders. Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingo_Root).
- [KingoRoot](http://www.kingoroot.com/): Android 6
- [Kingroot](https://kingroot.net/): Easy to use and fast rooting. Works on almost every Android phone.
- [Magisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445): requires custom ROM to be installed. Also see [this guide at AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/09/11/guide-play-pokemon-go-0-37-rooted-android-magisk/).
- [Ready2root](http://ready2root.com/) collected a lot of available rooting methods
- [Root Many Android](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460) (ICS/JB devices)
- [ROOTx](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2239958) supports a selection of devices produced prior to 10/2014
- [SRSRoot One Click Root for Android (SuperUser)](http://www.srsroot.com/) lists supported devices on their page. Download is an `.exe` file, so it probably requires Windows. Android 4.1 to 6.0 (?)
- [SuperOneClick](http://shortfuse.org/)
- [Towelroot](https://towelroot.com/) should support all phones with a kernel built before June 3, 2014
- [Universal Androot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=747598) - Read the page to see what devices are supported.  Mostly pre-2.2.1 versions of Android
- [Universal One Click](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=747598) - Make sure your device is support by reading the whole first post (probably not, last release was 10/2010 – so most likely 2.x devices only)
- [Unrevoked](http://unrevoked.com/): some older HTC devices only
- vRoot: Android 2.2 to 4.2
- [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/): The biggest resource for rooting, mods, etc.
- Also check out [the CyanogenMod wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) for other ways to root your device.

  - Here is a guide on how to [root Android without a computer](http://www.amongtech.com/root-android-without-computer/), naming each of the apps listed above and in-depth guides on how to use them.

## I've rooted my device. Now what?

- We have [another question about that!](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1/1465)
- If you have another method or know how to root a device that's not listed, feel free to add it to the list!  Just follow the same format.

Comment: Feel free to edit the wiki if you see improvements that can be made instead of down voting :)